# setting selected tag when ng-option is used

Tags: html, angularjs, select, ng-options, selected

I have this code which loads the value into drop down list through ng-option. But I am unable to set the default value when I use ng-option. Please find my code here and help me with this.

```
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2 pull-left">Quality<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
                          <div class="col-lg-8">
                 <select id="Quality" name="Quality" class="form-control" style="width:170px" ng-options="Q.value as Q.name for Q in vm.quality" ng-model="vm.Edit.Quality" tooltip="Quality is required"
                  tooltip-placement="top" required>

                             </select>
                        </div>
                  </div>
```

the angular code is here:

```
 vm.quality = [{ value: 'Satisfactory', name: "Satisfactory" },
        { value: 'NotSatisfactory', name: "Not Satisfactory" }];
        vm.Edit.Quality = vm.quality[0];
```

I have used last line `vm.Edit.Quality = vm.quality[0];`to set the selected(default) value to quality which is not working.

Comment: try this `vm.Edit.Quality = vm.quality[0].value`

Comment: very good answer :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
var vm = this;
   vm.quality = [{ value: 'Satisfactory', name: "Satisfactory" },
        { value: 'NotSatisfactory', name: "Not Satisfactory" }];
        vm.Quality = vm.quality[0].value;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl as vm">
 <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-2 pull-left">Quality<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
     <div>
      <select ng-options="Q.value as Q.name for Q in vm.quality"
                   ng-model="vm.Quality">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use ng-option this way:

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-lg-2 pull-left">Quality<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <select id="Quality" name="Quality" class="form-control" style="width:170px" ng-options="Q.value as Q.name for Q in vm.quality" ng-model="vm.Edit.Quality" tooltip="Quality is required"
              tooltip-placement="top" required>
      <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="0">Item 1</option>
      <option value="1">Item 2</option>
      <option value="2">Item 3</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```